# Adding dates to modifiers of react-day-picker to show holidays

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

Using react-day-picker (https://react-day-picker-v7.netlify.app/) I need to add dates to the modifiers property.  I have the dates (holiday name, holiday date) that I can pass to a function that can use it.  I currently have the dates getting to the function but I cannot get them formated correctly for the react-day-picker component to show them properly.  I only get 1 date to show up and the rest dont show.

I am passing an object made up of dates (holiday_date, holiday_name) and I am only getting the first holiday to show.  What am I doing wrong?

```
const modifiersHoliday = (holidays) => {
  const types = {};

  holidays.forEach((holi) => {
    const from = dayjs(holi.holiday_date).toDate();
    const to = dayjs(holi.holiday_date).toDate();
    const allDaysInTimeOff = getDatesBetweenRange(from, to);

    types["holiday"] = allDaysInTimeOff;
  });

  return types;
};
```